# Querystring not displayed in url w/ jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I send data (filter options) to the server via jQuery Ajax, process the results, all works fine. However, the querystring is not displayed in the url. But I need that for users can copy/paste the url and get the filtered content.

According to the docs concerning the passed data (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) :

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests.

Did i forget something? Any hints? Thanks!

Here is an example that resembles my working code:

```js
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myurl.com/handleAjax',
        type: "GET",
        data : {filter1 : 1, filter2 : 2}
        dataType : 'json'
  
    }).success(function(data) {
       ..do Stuff with data
         }
  })
```

Comment: `http:`myurl.com/handleAjax <--- `http://`myurl.com/handleAjax

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tipp, corrected the example and checked my working code, but still, the query string does not get appended.

Comment: You say it all works fine so presumably the server get the correct data in the url? Is it the url that the browser is displaying that you want to change? If so this is completely independent of what you are doing with your ajax call.

Comment: Yes sir, all works fine, the server receives the correct data and the parameters are appended. So you are saying the "appending" happens internally and the "displaying" in the url must be taken special care of?

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX request does not change the URL in the address bar, as you notice. This is by design, because the AJAX request is a separate, background request. It is completely different from the one that was used to load the page.

You can update the address in the address bar using the HTML 5 pushState function.

```
var data = {filter1 : 1, filter2 : 2};
var parameterizedData = $.param(data);
var queryString = "?" + parameterizedData;

window.history.pushState(null, "", queryString);
```